# Find out how long the order of nans in a column is

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, data-cleaning

I need to clean data by this specific rule (efficitently):

if there are 3 or fewer consecutive `NaN`s in a column, fill this `NaN` "chain" in df column by .fillna(method='ffill').
Otherwise leave it (for another method)

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[8001, 7999, 7998, np.NaN, 9900, 9342, 9324, 8534, 8358, 9457, np.nan, 8999, 8492, np.nan, np.nan],
                   "B":[201, 209, 298, 300,np.nan, 342, 324, 854, 858, 457, 145, 189, 192, 134, 135],
                   "C":[11991, 15631, 47998, 38030, 19900, 29342, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, 27245, 28999, 28492, 29334, 28234]}, 
                   index=pd.Index(['2019-06-17 00:00:00','2019-06-17 00:01:01', '2019-06-17 00:02:00', '2019-06-17 00:03:04', 
                                   '2020-06-17 00:04:00', '2020-06-17 00:05:00', '2020-06-17 00:06:00', '2020-06-17 00:07:00',
                                   '2020-06-17 00:08:00','2020-06-17 00:09:00','2020-06-17 00:10:00','2020-06-17 00:11:00',
                                   '2020-06-17 00:12:00','2020-06-17 00:13:00', '2020-06-17 00:14:00']))

df

                 Time     A     B       C
'2019-06-17 00:00:00'  8001   201   11991
'2019-06-17 00:01:01'  7999   209   15631
'2019-06-17 00:02:00'  7998   298   47998
'2019-06-17 00:03:04'  NaN    300   38030
'2020-06-17 00:04:00'  9900   NaN   19900
'2020-06-17 00:05:00'  9342   342   29342
'2020-06-17 00:06:00'  9324   324     NaN
'2020-06-17 00:07:00'  8534   854     NaN
'2020-06-17 00:08:00'  8358   858     NaN
'2020-06-17 00:09:00'  9457   457     NaN
'2020-06-17 00:10:00'   NaN   145   27245
'2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8999   189   28999
'2020-06-17 00:12:00'  8492   192   28492
'2020-06-17 00:13:00'   NaN   134   29334
'2020-06-17 00:14:00'   NaN   135   28234
```

Expected Result:

```
                 Time     A     B       C
'2019-06-17 00:00:00'  8001   201   11991
'2019-06-17 00:01:01'  7999   209   15631
'2019-06-17 00:02:00'  7998   298   47998
'2019-06-17 00:03:04'  7998   300   38030
'2020-06-17 00:04:00'  9900   300   19900
'2020-06-17 00:05:00'  9342   342   29342
'2020-06-17 00:06:00'  9324   324     NaN
'2020-06-17 00:07:00'  8534   854     NaN
'2020-06-17 00:08:00'  8358   858     NaN
'2020-06-17 00:09:00'  9457   457     NaN
'2020-06-17 00:10:00'  9457   145   27245
'2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8999   189   28999
'2020-06-17 00:12:00'  8492   192   28492
'2020-06-17 00:13:00'  8492   134   29334
'2020-06-17 00:14:00'  8492   135   28234
```

Comment: _NaNs in this row_ do you mean in a column? `C` is a column, not a row.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Sry i didnt use the right word i guess. With "in a row" i mean when the 3 rows which are located after each other are a NaN. (in the same column)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Like in the example, where the NaNs which are part of an order with <=3 NaNs following each other, are filled, but when the "chain" is longer than 3, they are left.

Comment: How about "3 or fewer consecutive `NaN`s in a column"

Comment: thats a very good phrasing^^, i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the size of consecutive NaN groups only and figure out which ones are smaller than your maximum gap size. Then by using that Boolean Series to mask the entire forward-filled column you can effectively only fill gaps that were smaller than or equal to your specified gap size.

```
def fwd_fill_gaps(df, col, gap_max):
    """ Fill conseuctive NaN when size is <= gap_max """

    s = df[col].notnull().cumsum().where(df[col].isnull())
    # Only True for NaN gaps of size <= gap_max
    s = s.groupby(s).transform('size').le(gap_max)

    return df[col].fillna(df[col].ffill().where(s), downcast='infer')


for col in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    df[col] = fwd_fill_gaps(df, col, gap_max=3)
```

---

```
                        A    B        C
2019-06-17 00:00:00  8001  201  11991.0
2019-06-17 00:01:01  7999  209  15631.0
2019-06-17 00:02:00  7998  298  47998.0
2019-06-17 00:03:04  7998  300  38030.0
2020-06-17 00:04:00  9900  300  19900.0
2020-06-17 00:05:00  9342  342  29342.0
2020-06-17 00:06:00  9324  324      NaN
2020-06-17 00:07:00  8534  854      NaN
2020-06-17 00:08:00  8358  858      NaN
2020-06-17 00:09:00  9457  457      NaN
2020-06-17 00:10:00  9457  145  27245.0
2020-06-17 00:11:00  8999  189  28999.0
2020-06-17 00:12:00  8492  192  28492.0
2020-06-17 00:13:00  8492  134  29334.0
2020-06-17 00:14:00  8492  135  28234.0
```